# Removing image size assignments - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I noticed that my images weren't crisp, and in the inspector found the piece of code that is making them blurry. But, now I don't know where to look within the actual code to remove this. It's not assigned in CSS. This is a portfolio page. I am using the Avada theme. Any ideas?

Link: http://www.madpeagames.com/gacha-sets/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4TSF.png)

Comment: It seems to be using a smaller rezised src of 359x359 instead of your full version of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your theme's demo I see sharp images and the image code is different. So, the problem is not caused by your theme.

My guess is that you use Jetpack's [Photon](https://jetpack.com/support/photon/) on your site. Try to deactivate the module and see if this changes anything.

However, image compression is a good thing, especially when using lots of images. Perhaps, if deactivating the Photon module solves the issue, [compare the speed of your website](https://gtmetrix.com/) with and without Photon. If it makes a notable difference, look in the Photon settings, to see what you could change to solve the issue.

Also, JPEG files (.jpg) may not be the best choice for your thumbnails, because you lose a lot of quality when the image isn't shown at its original size. If changing the settings doesn't help, you could try to use PNG files instead.

If Photon causes the issue and you don't find a way to solve it, while still compressing your images, I would suggest to contact [Jetpack support](https://jetpack.com/contact-support/). Alternatively you could try to use a different [WordPress plugin for image compression](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=image%20compression).

I hope that helps. GL!

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Photon is unfortunately disabled. I don't have any other media related plugins, and this seemed to have happened right when I updated the avada theme. It does seem like some sort of compression is happening... Still on the hunt.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Theme Fusion support? https://theme-fusion.com/support/